# Postgres - update table from another table based on multiple column match

Tags: database, postgresql, join

I have two tables below with sample data.

Table_1:

| start_datetimestamp | end_datetimestamp | t_no | lead_id | lead_a_id | lead_b_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-06 19:14:04 | 2023-01-06 21:00:05 | PKT - 19 | 23 |  |  |
| 2023-01-06 19:27:48 | 2023-01-06 22:39:06 | PKT - 16 | 27 | 07 | 89 |
| 2023-01-06 19:01:03 | 2023-01-06 22:47:00 | PKT - 21 | 56 | 11 | 23,78 |
| 2022-12-02 05:45:09 | 2022-12-02 05:54:41 | PKT - 45 | 67 | 10 |  |
| 2023-01-06 18:18:54 | 2023-01-06 18:31:46 | PKT - 32 | 07 | 14 | 97 |
| 2023-01-06 19:18:54 |  | PKT - 35 | 16 | 07 | 14 |

Table_2:

| lead_id | datetimestamp | pkt_type | t_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07 | 2023-01-06 19:28:48 |  |  |
| 78 | 2023-01-06 22:46:00 |  |  |
| 07 | 2023-01-06 18:31:42 |  |  |
| 23 | 2023-01-06 21:00:04 |  |  |
| 67 | 2022-12-02 05:30:09 |  |  |
| 16 | 2023-01-06 19:18:55 |  |  |

I need help to update the Table_2 columns(pkt_type,t_no) using below conditions -

- lead_id from Table_2 should match either with lead_id, lead_a_id or lead_b_id from Table_1.
- And datetimestamp from Table_2 should be in-between or equal to start_datetimestamp & end_datetimestamp from Table_1.
- if above conditions match update Table_2 pkt_type="Not Lead' if lead_id from Table_2 match with lead_a_id OR lead_b_id,
  else update Table_2 pkt_type="Lead' if lead_id from Table_2 is match with Table_1 lead_id.
- Also, update the t_no.

Output:

| lead_id | datetimestamp | pkt_type | t_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07 | 2023-01-06 19:28:48 | Not Lead | PKT - 16 |
| 78 | 2023-01-06 22:46:00 | Not Lead | PKT - 21 |
| 07 | 2023-01-06 18:31:42 | Lead | PKT - 32 |
| 23 | 2023-01-06 21:00:04 | Lead | PKT - 19 |
| 67 | 2022-12-02 05:30:09 |  |  |
| 16 | 2023-01-06 19:18:55 |  |  |

Setup table queries -

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
start_datetimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
end_datetimestamp timestamp without time zone,
t_no character varying(10) NOT NULL,
lead_id character varying(2) NOT NULL,
lead_a_id character varying(2),
lead_b_id character varying(5),PRIMARY KEY(start_datetimestamp, t_no, lead_id));
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES
      ('2023-01-06 19:14:04', '2023-01-06 21:00:05', 'PKT - 19', '23', '', '')
    , ('2023-01-06 19:27:48', '2023-01-06 22:39:06', 'PKT - 16', '27', '07', '89')
    , ('2023-01-06 19:01:03', '2023-01-06 22:47:00', 'PKT - 21', '56', '11', '23,78')
    , ('2022-12-02 05:45:09', '2022-12-02 05:54:41', 'PKT - 45', '67', '10', '')
    , ('2023-01-06 18:18:54', '2023-01-06 18:31:46', 'PKT - 32', '07', '14', '97')
    , ('2023-01-06 19:18:54', NULL, 'PKT - 35', '16', '07', '14')
    ;

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
lead_id character varying(2) NOT NULL,
datetimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
pkt_type character varying(10) NOT NULL,
t_no character varying(10) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(datetimestamp, lead_id));

INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES
      ('07', '2023-01-06 19:28:48', '', '')
    , ('78', '2023-01-06 22:46:00', '', '')
    , ('07', '2023-01-06 18:31:42', '', '')
    , ('23', '2023-01-06 21:00:04', '', '')
    , ('67', '2022-12-02 05:30:09', '', '')
    , ('16', '2023-01-06 19:18:55', '', '')
    ;
```

Test Env -
https://dbfiddle.uk/bwdeYkjD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 2 update statements as below:

```
update table_2
set pkt_type='Lead', t_no=table_1.t_no
FROM table_1
WHERE table_2.lead_id = table_1.lead_id
AND table_2.datetimestamp between table_1.start_datetimestamp 
AND table_1.end_datetimestamp;

update table_2
set pkt_type='Not Lead', t_no=table_1.t_no
FROM table_1
WHERE table_2.lead_id != table_1.lead_id 
  and table_2.datetimestamp between table_1.start_datetimestamp 
  and table_1.end_datetimestamp 
  AND (table_2.lead_id = table_1.lead_a_id
  OR table_2.lead_id = table_1.lead_b_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @anunaki. it's working fine, I just updated the last 2 condition in query-2 - ``` table_2.lead_id = any(string_to_array(table_1.lead_a_id, ',')) OR table_2.lead_id = any(string_to_array(table_1.lead_b_id, ',')) ```